# state manager that save data when app close for flutter

Tags: flutter, state-management

Is there any state manager for flutter that when app closes the data save. For example i have a shopping app and cart I have a model for cart but when I close app and reopen the saved data is lost.

What can I do for this problem?

I use the [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) but it doesn't save data when app closed.

Please give me a solution for develop cart list or something like to-do app (except SharedPreferences)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use shared preferences for data storage because it is only used to save key and value pairs . But you can use sqlite for permanent data storage. https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/sqlite